# UIImageView image not showing up on iPad Simulator

Tags: ios, interface-builder, ipad, ios-simulator

I have a Window in Interface Builder.  I dragged a UIImageView onto the Window and selected the image that I wanted to be displayed from Image View Attributes -> Image View -> Image, and it was on the drop down list.  I see the image on the Window screen.

However, when I go to File -> Simulate Interface, it only displays a black screen.

Am I doing something incorrectly?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Setting the image of a UIImageView in Interface Builder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734586/setting-the-image-of-a-uiimageview-in-interface-builder)

Comment: I had a similar problem, but it wasn't showing on the iPad device: [UIImage Showing in Simulator, but not on Device (iPad/iPhone)](http://jackofalltradesdeveloper.blogspot.com/2012/07/uiimage-showing-in-simulator-but-not-on.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your image is not part of the Simulator bundle, so the loading fails and your `UIImageView` will be blank.

Do the connection between image and `UIImageView` in code and it should show the image.

Like:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"cell.png"];
```

Once you have an `UIImage` you can then set `UIImageView` this way:

```
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

It may be because I renamed by UIViewController h, m and xib files.

I did rm -r on my Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/ folder. Quit the simulator. Then tried again. Worked.

Some strange caching issue, I suspect.